# How do you secure a firebase node that all users have write access to?

Tags: firebase, security, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I understand Firebase's security rules for allowing or denying write access for authorized users, however, in a case where you need to allow all users write access to a specific node, say for example in a chat application we need to allow all users to write messages to a support room for example ...

**What is the best approach / practice for preventing abuse of a firebase node to which all users have write access to?**

Aside from adding limits, like only allowing updates to a node every `x` number of minutes, are there any other approaches / suggestions out there?

Comment: If you want to allow users to edit messages, make sure they can only edit messages belonging to them

Comment: You could also validate the structure of your message objects. Examples in the docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data. And there is actually a specific example that may help your situation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#anonymous_chat_example

Comment: sure I understand that concept, but what about new messages? new data to a node that all users have write access to. What is to prevent a single user from posting 10,000 messages for example? just limits?